# To create fixed number turtles each with separate headings on fixed ycor and equidistant xcor

Tags: netlogo

I want to create 4 turtles on fixed pycor (like pycor = 10) and even spacing xcor   over that pycor; and also I want to make the headings of each turtles separate from other. The display is like

............. O ............. O .............. O ........... O ............
       (heading 45)     (heading 90)    (heading 230)  (heading 180)

O is the turtle here. My code is as below.

```
ask n-of 4 patches with [ pcolor = 18 and pycor = 10 ] [
   sprout-turtles 1 [
      set shape "default"
      set color blue
      set size 2
      set heading one-of [90 270]
    ] 
  ]
```

With this code turtles are created but many time with same heading, sometimes on same patch, sometimes neighboring patch as shown below

```
 ..........OOO...................O or .........OO..........O.........O...
```

but this i don't want. Should i have to use Create turtles four times separately specifying xcor, ycor and heading? Actually i don't want to use it four times. Please any suggestion and help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your heading problem is that `one-of` will randomly select one of the available values, so repeats are not unusual. Your separation problem is that `n-of` selects a random group of size n. Do you want specific values for the headings, or do you just want to make sure they are different?

Comment: thanx sir, I want specific values both for headings and xcor.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing you are taking from the patch to the turtle, you may as well just use `create-turtles` instead of `sprout-turtles` and then put them where you want. Typically, sprout is used when the particular patch meets relevant conditions - such as having lots of resources. Also, since you want specific values, using `one-of` or `n-of` will not work because they randomly select.

Instead you want something more like this (not tested):

```
let gap 15                      ; spacing between turtles
let directions [45 90 230 180]  ; heading values
let ii 0                        ; counter / index
repeat 4
[ create-turtles 1
  [ setxy (0 + ii * gap) 10
    set shape "default"
    set color blue
    set size 2
    set heading item ii directions
  ]
  set ii ii + 1
]
```